# Impedance matching: headphones out / hijacked op-amp pin -> guitar input

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, audio, impedance, guitar-pedal

I have a Vox "amplug" pocket amp which has a female 1/4" mono input, it's supposed to be dangling directly from the guitar's output jack, and has 3.5mm TRS headphones out. I'd like to feed this unit's output into another fx unit. (for now testing with ammoon "pock rock", a cheap knockoff of Line 6's pod mini)

My first attempt/test of course was to connect the left channel of the headphone out to the input of the Ammoon, which as i expected resulted in a very noisy connection with massive feedback, which was only usable when the amplug's volume was way down and not too much tone or gain. I then tried to put several values of resistors (300ish Ω to 100KΩ) in series and parallel with the signal. Though this made the overall signal weaker to some extent, it didn't change the noise/feedback in the signal.

Next i looked at the amplug's circuit board and located what looks like a dual op-amp chip, but the markings on it were unreadable because of some gunk that's impossible to clean off without probably scraping off the markings. Anyway probing this chip with a 100KΩ resistor going to the ammoon's input, i located 2 pins that give a cleaner version of the output, one of them much weaker than the other but otherwise sounding pretty much the same. There's less feedback and noise on these, but it's still far from perfect. (the amplug is the "metal" version, so it's inherently high gain and therefore kind of noisy)

So my question is, what's the best way to adjust the impedance of this little pocket amp to feed into another one that expects a hi-Z / instrument input?

Comment: I don't think this is an impedance issue. If the output is meant to drive out headphones, it may not be intended for connecting to guitar input on the next unit. If we don't have schematics, we don't know what's wrong and how to make them compatible.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by feedback

Comment: @tobalt a high pitched whiny sound, would probably be a better way to describe it.

Comment: What makes the IC in question "look like" a dual op amp?  Without any markings it could be any 8-pin IC.  This [teardown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qcQVjCmUDU) of the AC30 version shows several 8-pin ICs.  Why not just feed the headphone output to a passive attenuator before going into the FX unit?